# Find pci of hostbridge of a device in FreeBSD10

Tags: freebsd, pci

I have a pci address for a device, and need to find the pci address of its hostbridge. In FreeBSD 11 it is very easy to do that using "devinfo -v" as you can grep the pci address of the device and then you can find its parent in the tree which is the hostbridge. Now in FreeBSD 10 there is no any pci address in the output of the "devinfo -v". Example of "devinfo -v" output in FreeBSD 11:

```
pcib4 pnpinfo vendor=0x8086 device=0x2f08 subvendor=0x15d9 subdevice=0x0833 class=0x060400 at pci0:0:3:0 handle=\_SB_.PCI0.BR3A
      pci4
        mlx5_core1 pnpinfo vendor=0x15b3 device=0x1013 subvendor=0x15b3 subdevice=0x0010 class=0x020700 at pci0:3:0:0 handle=\_SB_.PCI0.BR3A.H000
        mlx5_core2 pnpinfo vendor=0x15b3 device=0x1013 subvendor=0x15b3 subdevice=0x0010 class=0x020700 at pci0:3:0:1 handle=\_SB_.PCI0.BR3A.H001
```

Example of "devinfo -v" output in FreeBSD 10:

```
pcib4 pnpinfo vendor=0x8086 device=0x2f08 subvendor=0x15d9 subdevice=0x0833 class=0x060400
      pci4
        mlx5_core1 pnpinfo vendor=0x15b3 device=0x1013 subvendor=0x15b3 subdevice=0x0010 class=0x020700
        mlx5_core2 pnpinfo vendor=0x15b3 device=0x1013 subvendor=0x15b3 subdevice=0x0010 class=0x020700
```

So You can see that the pci addresses are not appearing in output of FreeBSD10

Comment: Can you add examples from both systems which part is the address you are looking for? I could try to verify on my system but since I am not that familiar with PCI addressing I am not sure if what `devinfo -v` spits out is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2-step workaround. At first find device name:

```
pciconf -l -v | grep "pci0:2:0:0" | cut -f 1 -d @
```

In my case it's sdhci_pci0.

Then find location in devinfo:

```
$ devinfo | grep -B 5 sdhci_pci0
              pcm2
              pcm3
              pcm4
        pcib1
          pci2
            sdhci_pci0
```

Note:
On FreeBSD10.2-STABLE I can see PCI info in output of devinfo.

Comment: what if the module sdhci_pci0 is not loaded? then in pciconf output you will see "none" and thus it is not possible to continue and use devinfo

Comment: if no driver is attached, it's "unknown" node of "devinfo -v". But devices without drivers are not numbered.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to walk through the `dev` sysctl tree:

1. You can grep for the PCI address you have in the `%location` OID:

   ```
   $ sysctl dev | grep %location
   dev.hdac.1.%location: pci0:0:27:0 handle=\_SB_.PCI0.HDEF
   dev.hdac.0.%location: pci0:2:0:1
   dev.vgapci.0.%location: pci0:2:0:0 handle=\_SB_.PCI0.PEG3.MXM3
   dev.hostb.15.%location: pci0:255:5:3
   dev.hostb.14.%location: pci0:255:5:2
   ```
2. You can then find the parent using the %parent OID. For instance, the parent of `pci0:2:0:0` (listed in the example above) is `pci1`:

   ```
   $ sysctl dev.vgapci.0.%parent
   dev.vgapci.0.%parent: pci1
   ```
3. The parent has its own sysctl tree:

   ```
   $ sysctl dev.pcib.1.%location
   dev.pcib.1.%location: pci0:0:3:0 handle=\_SB_.PCI0.PEG3
   ```

Not the most straightforward approach, but it should work accross different versions of FreeBSD (and probably DragonFlyBSD FWIW).

Answer (score 0):

Try `devinfo -rv`.

A snippet of output on FreeBSD 10.3:

```
        atapci1 pnpinfo vendor=0x8086 device=0x27c0 subvendor=0x1043 subdevice=0x8179 class=0x01018f at p
ci0:0:31:2 handle=\_SB_.PCI0.IDE1
            Interrupt request lines:
                0x13
            I/O ports:
                0xb880-0xb88f
                0xbc00-0xbc03
                0xc000-0xc007
                0xc080-0xc083
                0xc400-0xc407
          ata2 at channel=0
          ata3 at channel=1
```